# intellij idea 14 and gradle issues when running integTests

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a gradle project imported into idea 14.0.3. The integration tests run fine from the command line. They were also running without any problems in idea 13 from the context menu (running single tests). However, in 14, when I use the context menu in IDE, for some reason the tests that depend on class path resources from src/integTest/resources are failing due to resource not being found. Any idea how I can add this folder in the classpath search in Intellij 14? Has anyone seen this issue before?

If I move the same resource to src/test/resources (or src/main/resources), the tests run fine. So it seems like intellij is not simply looking under src/integTest/resources.

Appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this before as well, add the following to your `build.gradle` file:

```
// work-around to fix IDE-run test failures (may be fixed in future Gradle versions)
    task copyMainResourcesToTest(type: Copy) {
    from "${projectDir}/src/main/resources"
    into "${buildDir}/classes/test"
}
processTestResources.dependsOn copyMainResourcesToTest

task copyTestResourcesToTest(type: Copy) {
    from "${projectDir}/src/test/resources"
    into "${buildDir}/classes/test"
}
processTestResources.dependsOn copyTestResourcesToTest
```

I think this may be resolved in the newest release of Gradle but I have not verified yet. You will want to update the paths for your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. On a first try, it still didn't work. I will play around with it a bit more to see if it is some configuration on my end. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is Bug ([IDEA-128966](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128966)) in IntelliJ 14.
The recommended workaround is something like this:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/integTest/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/integTest/resources')
    }
    if(System.properties.'idea.active') {
        main {
            resources.srcDir file('src/integTest/resources')
        }
    }
}
```

For our projects I changed that to:

```
if(System.properties.'idea.active') {
    test { //Add to test rather than main
```

That still works and I think it communicates the intent better.

---

This workaround assumes you have configured your integration tests like this in the `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceSets { 
    integrationTest { 
        java.srcDir file('src/integTest/java') 
        resources.srcDir file('src/inteTest/resources') 
    } 
}

configurations { 
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile 
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime 
}

task integrationTest(type: Test, dependsOn: jar) { 
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir 
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath 
}

build.dependsOn(integrationTest)
```

---

Note: This answer was originally deleted by a moderator because of a duplicate answer that I posted on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755843/). I now deleted my answer there (and added a link to here) because I think it fits this question better.